# How can I edit trees in Vim?

Tags: plugin-nerdtree

If I'm not mistaken, NerdTree and Fern are for viewing directories, not for editing general trees ([Ordered trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)#Plane_tree) of strings in CS terms)

If so, is there a way to edit general trees in Vim? (It should preserve the order of the leaves/branches instead of sorting them)

I don't care about the file format, so long as Vim shows it as a tree, similar to how NerdTree does it

[image]

but I want to edit this tree and the order of the nodes should be preserved.

The functionality I would expect from a tree editor:

- expand node
- collapse node
- expand node recursively
- collapse node recursively
- delete node and its subnodes
- copy/paste node and its subnodes
- move a node and its subnodes
- promote/demote a node and all its subnodes

All these operations are easy in a tree editor (1 or 2 keystrokes, no counting lines or selecting text).

Most important, a tree editor reads a tree and saves a tree. It does not allow it to turn into a non-tree at any time (I do not believe "vim outliners" fulfill this requirement, but I'd be happy to be corrected, if I'm wrong)

Comment: What type of trees?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! As Zoe says, it's not clear what types of tree-structures you mean. Code? Data? Some specific format (SGML, S-expr, &c.)? Please [edit] to add more details.

Comment: Also, note that plugin requests are off-topic. I've edited your question to focus on the problem; perhaps someone will be able to answer with "use this plugin."

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Edited. I hope it's clearer

Comment: "any type of tree data".... like XML? YAML?  What do you want Vim to do?  It can edit any kind of text file that would contain trees... but you want it to give it a display similar to how nerdtree does?

Comment: @Zoe I don't really care (see edit)

Comment: @alec I wish I knew how to make the Q clearer. I don't care about the file format, so long as it represents a tree of strings.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you fleshed out a bit about what sort of problem you are trying to solve / what functionality you want to have (a bit more than "edit").  For example, are you just trying to edit a list which is nested with indents?  If so, I'm not sure (other than perhaps some semantics around folding) how a plugin would add on top of standard vim.

Comment: @AndrewHo-Lee See edit.

Comment: Take a look at some of the outliner plugins (and possibly also wiki or mind map plugins).  I have no experience with any to recommend, but your use of tree sounds a lot like what some might describe as an outline.  Alternatively, you may find that `:set foldmethod=indent` and some key mappings gets you most of the way there.

Comment: "Most important, a tree editor reads a tree and saves a tree.  It does not allow it to turn into a non-tree at any time".  This is not possible.  As I said in the comments to Zoe's answer, vim is fundamentally a text editor.  As an analogy, when using it to edit JSON it is perfectly possible to write malformed JSON.  Even if you could disable all text editing mappings and then just map commands to add/remove etc nodes, I'm no longer convinced that vim is the right tool for the task here.  You may be better served by looking at tree / node / mind map / outline editors with vim-like mappings.

Comment: Your final requirement is simultaneously trivially always satisfied (e.g. in vim-orgmode, whatever edits you apply, you will always end up with _some_ tree: it might just be that the structure of that tree is changed more radically than you intended), and the hard part of your question. I suspect the only plausible way to achieve what you're aiming for would be to prevent editing entirely (via `'nomodifiable'` and then allow changes _only_ via your tightly defined set of editing functions).

Answer (score 3):

I doubt you'll find a "tree editor plugin" because Vim makes editing easy and the features that would ease the process for editing tree data are not unique to editing trees.  These are the features to learn that will make this easier for you...

**fold** commands like `za`, `zc` etc should solve the expand/collapse part of your question.  Folding is how child nodes are hidden from view beneath their parents.  Vim conveniently numbers the depth of folded content so you can `d38` or however many lines vim says are folded.  Maybe you want [folds to automatically close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24711212/vim-auto-fold-when-leaving-fold) when the cursor moves outside of them.  Various things like that can be achieved, you just have to know what it is that you want to achieve.

**motions** like `d2j` (to delete&copy the current line and two lines below) should solve the copy/paste (paste is `p` or `P` for after/before cursor).

I suggest to using:

```
set relativenumber
set number
```

in your `.vimrc`.  The `relativenember` allows you to see the count of lines for your motion (making it easier `d9j` *without* having to count or calculate 9, the 9 is displayed for you).

When you're comfortable with vim, things like `d9j` are very easy.

A deficit here is that it wants the mouse cursor to be at the top (or bottom) of a node, if you're in the middle of a node another keystroke or two (to navigate to top or bottom) would be required.  You could write some vimscript to accomplish this and any other desired features.

To keep the data preserved in its proper format (so the tree remains a proper tree) you'll want to use syntax plugins, for example [syntastic](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic).

See `:help fold`, `:help motion`, and `:help relativenumber`.
It might also be helpful to try `vimtutor` from the commandline or check out this [reference sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lwSf.jpg).

---

This method is relies certain formatting.  If your tree is a 1-line mass of `json` you can turn your unmanageable blob of gobbledygook into a nice tree with `jq` (and for other data types other tools can be used)...

1. `:%!jq .` and your buffer is now loaded with readable json.
2. `zM` (`zm` also worked) to recursively fold the giant tree and `zc` to open one level and now we can easily browse and edit via the folded elements.
3. And `:%s/\s\|\n//g` turns it back to unreadable mass, (though with 45K lines I need to do two separate search/replaces or vim will crash).

Comment: Are you suggesting editing text files and pretending they are trees?

Comment: I mean, you said any format. Folds are technically a type of tree

Comment: @bobcat vim is a *text* editor, so at its heart a buffer (usually) contains text.  Anything on top of that to manipulate filesystems such as nerdtree is essentially mappings and other niceities on top of a bunch of text.

Comment: @Zoe I guess you've never used an actual tree editor, if you think *this* is tree editing.

Comment: I haven't, no, but you aren't giving us a lot to go on here. You present two directory trees as failed alternatives, and say it's fine in any format (it clearly isn't fine in any format if folds aren't an option). You'll have to add more details on the actual type of trees you want (and probably an underlying data format, because any doesn't hold, and is potentially harder to find solutions for). And this is still tree editing if you use it like trees. A super tedious and inefficient type, but nonetheless editing of _a_ type of tree in any format.

Comment: *"d9j without having to count or calculate 9, the 9 is displayed for you"* Arghh.... `v` select text `d`.

Comment: @Zoe see the very last edit.

Comment: @bobcat no `v` required.  This answer appears to me to solve all the points you've described in your question.  If it doesn't you need to specify *how* it does not and *what specifically you're hoping for*.

Comment: note that deleting/moving/etc. a closed fold is exactly like a recursive operation on nodes.

Answer (score 3):

This site is neither "advice me a plugin" nor "write a plugin for me" board. If you need some functionality no one tried to implement yet then go write it yourself.

Neither NERDTree nor Fern, Dirvish and whatsoever are "magic". They all are just text buffers pretending to look like trees.

As "a proof of concept":

```
function! ShowTree(json_data) abort
    new
    setlocal buftype=acwrite cursorline shiftwidth=2
    setlocal foldmethod=manual foldtext=getline(v:foldstart)
    let l:root = json_decode(join(a:json_data))
    if type(l:root) == v:t_dict
        call ShowTreeHelper(l:root, 0)
    elseif type(l:root) == v:t_list
        for l:item in l:root
            call ShowTreeHelper(l:item, 0)
        endfor
    endif
    call deletebufline("", 1)
    setlocal foldlevel=99
endfunction

function! ShowTreeHelper(tree, level) abort
    let l:indent = repeat(" ", a:level * shiftwidth())
    if !has_key(a:tree, "children")
        call append("$", l:indent . nr2char(0x1f341) . a:tree.name)
        return
    endif

    call append("$", l:indent . nr2char(0x1f33f) . a:tree.name)
    let l:start = line("$")
    for l:child in a:tree.children
        call ShowTreeHelper(l:child, a:level + 1)
    endfor
    execute l:start..",$fold"
endfunction
```

Now to show some random stuff:

```
let foo =<< trim END
    { "name": "vim82",
        "children": [
            { "name": "autoload",
                "children": []
            },
            { "name": "colors",
                "children": [
                    { "name": "tools",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    { "name": "blue.vim" },
                    { "name": "default.vim" }
                ]
            },
            { "name": "gvim"},
            { "name": "vim"}
        ]
    }
END
call ShowTree(foo)
```

```
vim82
  autoload
  colors
    tools
    blue.vim
    default.vim
  gvim
  vim
```

Then after another 500 lines of code implementing boring UI for editing operations you're done.

Comment: *"A plugin with your requested functionality does not exist"* is a perfectly good answer, if that's the case. Not sure what the purpose of your code is, if as you say, Vim cannot do what I want.

Comment: @bobcat I did not say it does not exist. Just I haven't heard of one. But it's perfectly possible to write such stuff.

Comment: This is really cool.... would displaying a count of the children be easy to do?

Comment: @alec Yes, quite trivial. The only point (if you really speak of number of nodes in a subtree) is that we can get count only after subtree is fully traversed, so we have to set parent item just before return.

Answer (score 1):

I developed the following treectrl library plugin (in 2006):

https://github.com/yegappan/treectrl

You can use this plugin from other plugins to easily create
and manage trees. You can refer to the help for more information:

https://github.com/yegappan/treectrl/blob/master/doc/treectrl.txt

I haven't worked on this plugin recently.

Comment: Does your plugin *require* that other plugins leverage the features provided by this one to achieve any functionality?  Or does your plugin here provide certain features on its own?  It sounds like it's intended to be used as a base plugin providing features for other plugins.

Comment: A plugin can use the treectrl plugin to display any information in a tree in a Vim window. The treectrl plugin itself doesn't provide any other functionality (other than the functions needed to manage the tree).

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer S-expression trees, I can recommend [guns/vim-sexp](https://github.com/guns/vim-sexp) or [my fork of the same](https://github.com/benknoble/vim-sexp) (changes mostly consist of autoloading and using more filetype mechanisms, rather than global things). Pair with [tpope/vim-sexp-mappings-for-regular-people](https://github.com/tpope/vim-sexp-mappings-for-regular-people) for sane vim-like mappings.

This should cover your requirements:

- expand node
- collapse node
- expand node recursively
- collapse node recursively

Yeah, no cigar here, though you could use a `foldmethod` with `syntax` or something else that understands your S-expressions.

- delete node and its subnodes: `dab` is enough, that's pure vim.
- copy/paste node and its subnodes: idem. `yab` for copy; `p` for paste
- move a node and its subnodes: doable with copy-paste, but I prefer `>f`/`<f`/`>e`/`<e`/`<(`/`>(`/`<)`/`>)` from tpope's mappings
- promote/demote a node and all its subnodes: I would use `<Plug>(sexp_splice_list)` (`dsf`), `<Plug>(sexp_raise_list)`/`<Plug>(sexp_raise_element)`, and `<Plug>(sexp_convolute)` for promotion. Demotion might be a little harder, but with [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) `ysafb` is probably enough (and `ysaf<C-f>` to tag the demoted node).